# Can I exercise rights related to a new rating for which a new license document has been issued before I actually go and collect it?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, pilot-certification, easa

Trying to figure this one out but no guidance anywhere other than lots of opinions (which I'm actively seeking).

I'm planning a few flights in the coming days - just last month, I completed a checkride for the EASA competency based IR rating. The license has been issued and I can pick it up at the CAA office in person (don't ask) in one of the Baltic states. Thing is, I'm 1,5k km away where my domicile is and don't want to spend tons of cash and time to go get it.

Thus the question, can i legally fly IFR next week since I'm current and I have the rating even though the physical document I have in my hand does not list it? (The CAA website upon login does). Would this 'fly' in case of a ramp check after landing abroad?

Best,
private pilot

Comment: Well in North America you are supposed to have your docs on your person, same as a driver's license, so I would think you would get dinged for not having it in Europe as well.  You should be able to find the EASA regulation on it easily enough.

Comment: They didn't give you a temporary certificate??

Comment: Had the same issue, was not allowed to exercise my IR(R) until I had the silly piece of paper in my hand. Crazy rules as usual with aviation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the wording you're looking for is in Part-FCL, FL045 - Obligation to carry and present documents (Emphasis mine)

> A valid licence and a valid medical certificate shall always be carried by the pilot when exercising the **privileges of the licence**.

In my opinion, this indicates that you may not exercise the privileges of your license (ie, the IR) without having on you evidence of that rating. Whether a printout from the CAA website would do, is entirely open to opinion. I think the best advice would be to call them and ask them directly.